# I need to convert some code so that it works with an input and output file text

Tags: c++

I have a program that reverses the letters in a sentence but keeps the words in the same order. I need to change the code from an iostream library to an fstream library where the user inputs a sentence into an input file("input.txt") and the program outputs the reverse into an output text file.

example of input:

```
This problem is too easy for me. I am an amazing programmer. Do you agree?
```

Example of output:

```
sihT melborp si oot ysae rof em. I ma na gnizama remmargorp. oD uoy eerga?
```

The code I already have:

```
int main()
{
    int i=0, j=0, k=0, l=0;
    char x[14] = "I LOVE CODING";
    char y[14] = {'\0'}; 
    for(i=0; i<=14; i++) { 
        if(x[i]==' ' || x[i]=='\0')  {
            for(j=i-1; j>=l; j--) 
            y[k++] = x[j];
            y[k++] = ' ';  
            l=i+1;
         }
    } 

    cout << y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there are reason you are not using std::string for this?

Comment: Put the code you have that reverses words into a function.   Then create a loop which reads input, passes the input to that function, and outputs the result.  Before the loop, open input and output files as needed.   Easy.   You need to actually do your own homework (you won't learn anything of use if you don't) so I'll leave producing code as an exercise.

Comment: Hello Jared, wellcome to S.O. You need to iterate over your string,@Gardener ask you a great question, there is a reason to not use `std::string`?? if not you really should use it.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you submitted looks much more like something from C rather than from C++.  Not sure if you are familiar std::string and function calls.  As the code you wrote is pretty sophisticated, I will assume that you are.

Here is an example of how to use fstream.  I almost always you getline for the input because I find that it gets me into fewer problems.

I then almost always use stringstream for parsing the line because it neatly splits the lines at each space.

Finally, I try to figure out a while() or do{}while(); loop that will trigger off of the input from the getline() call.

Note that if the word ends in a punctuation character, to keep the punctuation at the end, the reverse_word() function has to look for non-alpha characters at the end and then save that aside.  This could be done by only reversing runs of alphas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

///////////////////
/// return true if ch is alpha
/// return false for digits, punctuation, and all else
bool is_letter(char ch){
  if((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') ||
      (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
////////
// Only reverse the letter portion of each word
//
std::string reverse_word(std::string str)
{
  std::string output_str; // Probably have to create a copy for output
  output_str.reserve(str.length()); // reserve size equal to input string

  // iterate through each letter of the string, backwards,
  // and copy the letters to the new string
  char save_non_alpha = 0;

  for (auto it = str.rbegin(); it != str.rend(); it++) {
    /// If the last character is punctuation, then save it to paste on the end
    if(it == str.rbegin() && !is_letter(*it)) {
      save_non_alpha = *it;
    } else {
      output_str += *it;
    }
  }
  if(save_non_alpha != 0) {
    output_str += save_non_alpha;
  }
  return output_str;  // send string back to caller
}

int main()
{
  std::string input_file_name{"input.txt"};
  std::string output_file_name{"output.txt"};
  std::string input_line;

  std::ifstream inFile;
  std::ofstream outFile;

  inFile.open(input_file_name, std::ios::in);
  outFile.open(output_file_name, std::ios::out);

  // if the file open failed, then exit
  if (!inFile.is_open() || !outFile.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "File " << input_file_name
        << " or file " << output_file_name
        << " could not be opened...exiting\n";
    return -1;
  }


  while (std::getline(inFile, input_line)) {
    std::string word;
    std::string sentence;

    std::stringstream stream(input_line);

    // I just like stringstreams.  Process the input_line
    // as a series of words from stringstream.  Stringstream
    // will split on whitespace.  Punctuation will be reversed with the
    // word that it is touching
    while (stream >> word) {
      if(!sentence.empty())  // add a space before all but the first word
        sentence += " ";
      word = reverse_word(word);
      sentence += word;
    }
    outFile << sentence << std::endl;

  }
  inFile.close();
  outFile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it was extremely helpful! The only problem I have is that in the output, the punctuation is in the slightly wrong place.

Comment: So, you want the punctuation to act as a delimiter, or to sort to the end of a word.  I guess it would probably be eaiser to sort the punctuation to the end of the word, but it could be done either way.

Comment: Yea to sort to the end cause for the example:                                                                   sihT melborp si oot ysae rof .em I ma na gnizama .remmargorp oD uoy ?eerga     ,It Should be: sihT melborp si oot ysae rof em. I ma na gnizama remmargorp. oD uoy eerga?

Comment: Do you understand the rbegin() iterator call?  If so, please accept the answer.

Comment: Just 1 more question, is it possible to do this program without the use of 'auto'?

Comment: Do you have access to a debugger?

Comment: Yes but my assignment does not allow me to use the auto function

Comment: Then set a breakpoint right after the auto variable has been assigned and you will be able to see the type.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `std::string` to store the string, and benefit from `std::vector` and `const_iterator` to make better use of C++ features:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::string s("This problem is too easy for me. I am an amazing programmer. Do you agree?");
  const char delim = ' ';
  std::vector<std::string> v;
  std::string tmp;

  for(std::string::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i <= s.end(); ++i)
  {
    if(*i != delim && i != s.end())
    {
      tmp += *i;
    }else
    {
      v.push_back(tmp);
      tmp = ""; 
    }
  }

  for(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) 
  {
    std::string str = *it,b;
    for(int i=str.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
      b+=str[i];
    std::cout << b << " ";
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> sihT melborp si oot ysae rof .em I ma na gnizama .remmargorp oD uoy ?eerga

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Do you know how to fix where the punctuation is, its in slightly the wrong place.